# ADO.NET Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ado.net

I have little bit knowledge on Entity Framework.As we can do almost all operations using 
MS Application Block,What are the benefits do we gather using Entity Framework ?

Comment: There are some good posts on this site already, and elsewhere on the web.  Once you've learned a bit, ask some more specific questions here.  Try http://whitepapers.techrepublic.com.com/abstract.aspx?docid=257013 and http://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/archive/2008/05/19/why-use-the-entity-framework-yeah-why-exactly.aspx for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Application Blocks are meant to help you add standard functionality to your applications without hand-rolling the code yourselves.

The Entity Framework is an ORM (Object-Relational Mapper) that is meant to make mapping the data in your database to Objects in your code seamless.

<strike>Two completely seperate tools.</strike>